# Pause video when playing another video - continue when closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have 1 video auto playing on my website - that won't be an issue but I also want to have 6 seperate videos (not autoplay) that can be activated trough hitting a button that pops up a lightbox with an embed video.

So here's the deal, when playing one of the seperate video's the main video (number 1) should pause.. After closing the lightbox.. video number1 should continue.

Summary: 1 video plays when opening the page - 6 optional videos can be watched when hitting their thumbs - 1st video should pause on opening one of those videos - and continue after closing them!

Hope someone can help :D

Comment: Depends on the library you are using for the video playback. Most libraries  have functionality that let you pause and resume video's

Comment: Are you just using the <video> attribute?

Comment: If you don't know how to manipulate `<video>` object, take a look at a well made tutorial from MSDN here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924823(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using the HTML5 video player, you'll need to hook into the `play` event of all the non-main videos.

When that event is fired, pause the main video,

```
$(".non_main_videoclass").on("play", function() {
    //pause the main video
    $("#mainvid_id").pause();
});
```

Then when the secondary video ends call `.play()` on the main video.

```
$(".non_main_videoclass").on("ended", function() {
    //play the main video
    $("#mainvid_id").play();
});
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) is a reference of all the HTML5 video player methods and events.

*Note you may have to cover some other use cases i.e. where the user pauses a non-main video instead of just letting it finish. Otherwise the main video will not restart.